# Сортировка данный в цикле в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Имеется файл с данными по успеваемости абитуриентов. Он представляет из себя набор строк, где в каждой строке записана следующая информация:

**Фамилия;Оценка_по_математике;Оценка_по_физике;Оценка_по_русскому_языку**

```
Atcheson;29;60;70
Holmes;84;72;75
Raleigh;45;46;97
Keat;75;66;60
Laird;51;63;50
Creighton;78;34;81
Hardman;90;66;70
Coleman;87;69;29
Johnson;33;81;92
Fraser;37;65;26
Gill;96;70;71
```

Поля внутри строки разделены точкой с запятой, оценки — целые числа.

Необходимо написать программу, которая считывает файл с подобной структурой и для каждого абитуриента выводит его среднюю оценку по этим трём предметам на отдельной строке, соответствующей этому абитуриенту.

Также в конце файла, на отдельной строке, через пробел нужно записать средние баллы по математике, физике и русскому языку по всем абитуриентам:

```
Sample Input:
Петров;85;92;78
Сидоров;100;88;94
Иванов;58;72;85

Sample Output:
85.0
94.0
71.666666667
81.0 84.0 85.666666667
```

В итоге получился примерно такой код:

```
lst = []
sred = []
fst = []
scnd = []
thr = []
with open("dataset_3363_4.txt", 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        lst.extend([line.strip().split(';')])
for i in lst:
    sred.extend((int(i[1]))*2)
    fst.extend([int(i[1])])
    scnd.extend([int(i[2])])
    thr.extend([int(i[3])])
f = open("1.txt", "w+")
for i in sred:
    print (i, file = f)
print ((sum(fst)/len(fst)), (sum(scnd)/len(scnd)), (sum(thr)/len(thr)), file = f)
```

который должен выводить среднее значение по предметам в списке, но не удается его заставить функционировать. Выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    sred.extend((int(i[1]))*2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Подскажите, каким образом можно заставить функционировать код и по возможности, как лучше его оптимизировать?**

Comment: `(int(i[1]))*2`  - Это Вы находите средний балл по трём предметам?

Comment: Ещё советую почитать про методы `extend` и `append`, т.к. в Вашем случае `append` делает именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обернуть в классы будет выглядеть приличнее.

Алгоритм: построчно парсим строки, вытаскиваем имена студентов и их оценки, и добавляем их в список. После подсчитываем среднее значение и добавляем его в конец списка.

```py
data = """
Atcheson;29;60;70
Holmes;84;72;75
Raleigh;45;46;97
Keat;75;66;60
Laird;51;63;50
Creighton;78;34;81
Hardman;90;66;70
Coleman;87;69;29
Johnson;33;81;92
Fraser;37;65;26
Gill;96;70;71
"""

students = list()

for line in data.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    parts = line.split(';')
    name = parts[0]

    # Получаем список от второго элемента до последнего,
    # и приводим каждый элемент к числу
    rating = list(map(int, parts[1:]))
    mean = sum(rating) / len(rating)

    info = list()
    info.append(name)
    info.extend(rating)
    info.append(mean)

    students.append(info)

# Выводим имя студента и его среднюю оценку по предметам (последний элемент)
for st in students:
    print('{}: {:.2f}'.format(st[0], st[-1]))

print()
# По списку студентов составляет списки с оценками по каждому предмету
p1 = [st[1] for st in students]
p2 = [st[2] for st in students]
p3 = [st[3] for st in students]

print(sum(p1) / len(p1))
print(sum(p2) / len(p2))
print(sum(p3) / len(p3))
```

---

Можно сделать более универсальным -- количество оценок может быть любое:

```py
students = list()

for line in data.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    parts = line.split(';')
    name = parts[0]
    rating = list(map(int, parts[1:]))
    mean = sum(rating) / len(rating)

    students.append(
        (name, rating, mean)
    )

for st in students:
    print('{}: {:.2f}'.format(st[0], st[-1]))

print()

# Количество оценок определяем по количеству оценок последнего студента
for i in range(len(rating)):
    p = [s[1][i] for s in students]
    print(sum(p) / len(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто исправленная ошибка в коде Автора.
Метод `extend` заменён за ненадобностью на `append`, и исправлено нахождение среднего балла ученика.

```
lst = []
sred = []
fst = []
scnd = []
thr = []
with open("dataset_3363_4.txt", 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        lst.append(line.strip().split(';'))

for i in lst:
    sred.append(( int(i[1]) + int(i[2]) + int(i[3]) ) / 3)
    fst.append(int(i[1]))
    scnd.append(int(i[2]))
    thr.append(int(i[3]))
f = open("1.txt", "w+")
for i in sred:
    print (i, file = f)
print ((sum(fst)/len(fst)), (sum(scnd)/len(scnd)), (sum(thr)/len(thr)), file = f)
```

Answer (score 0):

У PyCham есть пошаговое выполнение, очень помогает в таких случаях. Ну если без заморочек и легко читаем, то вот:

```
students = {}
result = [0, 0, 0]
with open('file.txt') as A:
    for line in A:
        student = line.strip().split(';')
        students[student[0]] = student[1:]
for i in students:
    students[i] = [int(j) for j in students[i]]
    students[i].append(sum(students[i]) / 3)
    result[0] += students[i][0]
    result[1] += students[i][1]
    result[2] += students[i][2]
for i in students:
    print(students[i][3])
k = len(students)
print(result[0] / k, result[1] / k, result[2] / k)
```